# Delete specific Excel sheet without ActiveX

Tags: excel, matlab

I'm currently writing a conversion function that takes data and creates an `.xls` file where part of the data becomes the sheet names.
My problem is, `xlswrite` automatically creates 3 default sheets with default names when it creates a new Excel file. Of course, these usually don't match the names in my data, so after my conversion is done, my Excel file looks almost fine, it simply has 3 leading sheets which are not supposed to be there.

Is there a way, without using ActiveX, to either stop `xlswrite` from creating those sheets in the first place, or delete them afterwards?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid ActiveX? Everything I found that edits excel files seems to make use of it. If at least one part of your data has a fixed name, you could perhaps write to (a copy of) an Excel file with only this tab?

Comment: Well, it's not "pure" Matlab. That's pretty much my only reason. I don't use Java in Matlab for the same reason. I like to try doing stuff without relying on independent APIs or resources. If there's no other choice, I'll go with ActiveX, but if there is, I'd like to know. I like the idea of keeping a blank prepared copy, but my data has no fixed name, so I'd have to include dummy data with such a name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out `xlswrite` actually uses AxtiveX internally, so the answer is

**No, there is no way.**

Just use ActiveX.

Answer (score 0):

I made a copy of a template Excel file with a single named sheet from the program directory to the current directory, and then write to this file.

Use

`fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'))`

to get the path to the program file.